# Sum of $(-1)$ to the number of prime factors bounded?

Tags: number-theory

Define a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ to be $f(1) = 1, f(p) = -1$ for all prime p, and for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N},f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

Try to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ is not bounded.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This $f(n)$ is called the Liouville lambda function $\lambda(n)$ (not to be confused with Carmichael lambda).

Comment: And your answer can be found by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function

Comment: @GEdgar Nope, I tried that, and it just states the fact, together with some asymptotic bounds on the unboundedness (does that even make sense?). There is no proof on the page.

Comment: The question is probably to show that the sequence $(g(n))_n$ is not bounded, where $g(n)=\sum\limits_{i\leqslant n}f(i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function

$f(x) = \lambda(x)$, Liouville's lambda function.

$\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda(k) = L(n)$ was considered by Pólya.  We see the statement: $L(n) > 0.06\;\sqrt{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.  This certainly shows that the series is not bounded.

Comment: apparently the reference is P. Borwein, R. Ferguson, and M. J. Mossinghoff, Sign Changes in Sums of the Liouville Function, Mathematics of Computation 77 (2008), no. 263, 1681–1694.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ converges, then $a_n$ must tend to $0$. Since $f(n)$ clearly does not tend to $0$, your sum doesn't converge.

Comment: He didnt ask you to prove whether it converged or not. He asked about boundedness.

Comment: The OP changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

The result cited on Wikipedia refers to a paper on oscillation theorems by Anderson and Stark.  I'm not sure there is a simpler way to prove this than using the analyticity of the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(n)/n^s = \zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$.

If the partial sums of $\lambda(n)$ are bounded, then the Dirichlet series converges for $\Re s > 0$ and can be bounded nicely in terms of $s$ using Abel summation.  However, $\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1/2$.  An identical argument shows that $L(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda(n)$ cannot be bounded by any $O(n^{1/2 - \epsilon})$ function.